# Spark SQL: have all conditions of a case when evaluated

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'd like to create overlapping groups of dates for a summary table I'm working on and to do I'm trying to create a case when that evaluates all possible conditions, not short-circuiting after the first true condition.

For example if the date is `2022-04-05` This should be in the group for April and all subsequent months.

I tried

```
        case
            when T.InstanceDate <= ("2022-01-31") Then "January"
            when T.InstanceDate <= ("2022-02-28") Then "February"
            when T.InstanceDate <= ("2022-03-31") Then "March"
            when T.InstanceDate <= ("2022-04-30") Then "April"
            when T.InstanceDate <= ("2022-05-31") Then "May"
            when T.InstanceDate <= ("2022-06-30") Then "June"
            else "other"
        end as Group_Name,
```

But this short circuits and the date is only counted for April.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "in the group"? Can you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: So using the example date ```2022-04-05 ``` I would want
 ```(group_name,count) as (values
  (April ,1),
  (May,1),
  (June,1))```
and I'm currently getting:
```(group_name,count) as (values
  (April ,1),
  (May,0),
  (June,0))```